# NAT (network address translator) and mapping IP/port pair

Tags: ip, port, nat

I'm not sure if the NAT can mapping a unique external IP / port to multiple internal IP / port pairs.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is conceivable that a process can NAT one incoming packet to multiple destinations, creating a new packet for each. Whether this is functionally useful depends on the underlying protocol. This would likely break TCP operation quite spectacularly if communication were expected to be bidirectional for more than one, for example.

If you're looking for inbound communication only without replies from some hosts, GRE tunnel to the receiving host and a filter on inbound packets along with a non-learning bridge interface (port mirroring) can also serve the need.

Answer (score 0):

A DNAT rule selector does not just contain the destination IP address and a port number, it also at least would contain the protocol (tcp or udp), also some implementations (namely netfilter) would allow for additional selector criteria like the incoming interface, source IP address or source port address, so you would have significantly more permutations to select from.